# No me ejecuta el código JavaScript

Tags: javascript

**No me muestra el codigo en la pagina donde lo estoy haciendo, empece hace muy poco a aprender
este lenguaje y es el primer codigo que escribo solo. No se donde esta el error, busque
soluciones en varias paginas pero ninguna me puedo solucionar el problema**
```

````
  const contenedor = document.querySelector(".flex-container");

function crearTaza(color,modelo,precio,img){
     color= `<h2> ${color} </h2>`;
      modelo=`<h3> ${modelo} </h3>`;
        precio=`<p> Precio: <b> ${precio} </b> </p>`;
          img="<img src:'taza.png'>";
        return [img,color,modelo,precio];

}
   let documentFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

  var words=['Negro','Azul','Rojo','Blanco','Amarillo','Verde','Celeste','Marron','Rosa'];
    var number= Math.floor(Math.random()*words.length);
   var word= words[number];
    for (var i=0; i<15; i++){
         let colorRandom = (Math.random()*words);
        let modeloRandom = Math.round(Math.random()*25);
         let precioRandom = Math.round(Math.random()*1000+299);
        let taza = crearTaza(`Taza ${i}`,`Color ${colorRandom}`,`Modelo ${modeloRandom}`, 
     precioRandom);
       let div = document.createElement(div);
         div.classList.add(`item-${i}`,`flex-item`);
         contenedor.innerHTML = taza[0] + taza[1] + taza[2] + taza[3];
       documentFragment.appendChild(div);
    }
   
    contenedor.appendChild(documentFragment);
```
````

Answer (score 1):

En problema en tu código es que no estás usando las comillas para indicar el tipo de elemento que quieres crear aquí:

```
   let div = document.createElement(div);
```

Debes colocarlo así:

```
   let div = document.createElement('div');
```

Por otra parte, el código que usas para obtener el color aleatorio, no es correcto.

Así debería funcionar:

```js
  const contenedor = document.querySelector(".flex-container");

function crearTaza(color,modelo,precio,img){
     color= `<h2> ${color} </h2>`;
     modelo=`<h3> ${modelo} </h3>`;
     precio=`<p> Precio: <b> ${precio} </b> </p>`;
     img="<img src:'taza.png'>";
     return [img,color,modelo,precio];

}
   let documentFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

    var words=['Negro','Azul','Rojo','Blanco','Amarillo','Verde','Celeste','Marron','Rosa'];
    var number= Math.floor(Math.random()*words.length);
    var word= words[number];
    for (var i=0; i<15; i++){
        let colorRandom =words[Math.floor(Math.random()*words.length)];       
        let modeloRandom = Math.round(Math.random()*25);
        let precioRandom = Math.round(Math.random()*1000+299);
        let taza = crearTaza(`Taza ${i}`,`Color ${colorRandom}`,`Modelo ${modeloRandom}`, 
     precioRandom);
        let div = document.createElement('div');
        div.classList.add(`item-${i}`,`flex-item`);
        contenedor.innerHTML = taza[0] + taza[1] + taza[2] + taza[3];
        documentFragment.appendChild(div);
    }
   
    contenedor.appendChild(documentFragment);
```

```html
<div class="flex-container"></div>
```

Comment: Me deja ejecutarlo si apreto en ejecutar tu comentario, pero si yo copio lo mismo y lo ejecuto en mi editor de texto, me dice que innerHTML no esta definido, es nulo; copie y pegue tal cual el codigo que mandaste tambien, pero aun me aparece lo mismo.

Comment: @ErwinDitter ¿qué navegador / versión estás usando? ¿Revisaste la consola a ver si hay otros errores? Lo único por lo que se me ocurre que no funcione en tu contexto es [que tengas una versión de navegador que no soporte `querySelector`](https://caniuse.com/queryselector).

Comment: uso google chrome version 92, no se por que me pasa eso, es el unico error que aparece, en internet edge tambien.

Comment: `querySelector` es compatible con todas las versiones de Chrome y de Edge, por tanto debe ser otro el problema, @ErwinDitter